# Testing click in input field with resulting text selection

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, capybara

I implemented following behavior for a input field: If the user clicks on the field it will set the whole input-value as selection;

```
$('.my_div input').on('click', function(event){
    this.setSelectionRange(0, this.value.length);
  }
);
```

Now I'm not quite sure how to test this behavior. Rough idea is to trigger the 
click and then check the selection of the field. But unfortunatly I have no idea how to optain the current selection of the input.

Any tip regarding a testing approach for described behavior would be welcome!

Comment: when you say test, do you mean how to check that the whole text is selected or what exactly?

Comment: yes my acceptance test should cover the expected result, so I want to test that the whole text in the input field is selected if the user has clicked on this field

Comment: `$(this).val()` will give you the current value of the input.

Comment: maybe you are using the wrong set of tools and wrong layer to test this? how about teaspoon? thats my 2 cents

Answer (score 0):

Right after just grab the start and end of the selection and if the start is at 0 and the end is at the input length then everything is selected.

```js
$('.my_div input').on('click', function(event){
    this.setSelectionRange(0, this.value.length);

    var start = event.target.selectionStart;
    var end = event.target.selectionEnd;
    if(start==0 && end==$(this).val().length)
        console.log('everything is selected');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='my_div'>
  <input type='text'>
  </div>
<input type='text'>
```

Comment: thx for your sniplet, but I need a solution which I can integrate within my acceptance test suite which checks this from the behaviour perspective (simulating the user in an headless browser), so the actual script adding this functionality should stay untouched

Comment: you could move those 4 lines into a `$('input').on('select',function(event){//move those lines here});`

Answer (score 0):

With capybara you can use page.evaluate_script to execute some javascript and return the result.  Something like

page.evaluate_script("[$('.my_div input')[0].startSelection,$('.my_div input')[0].endSelection]")

should return an array with the start and end selection positions which you can then verify.